# Не могу понять, какое из окончаний правильное

Tags: падежи, прилагательные

Нубский вопрос из четвертого класса, но для меня вопросы звучат «равноправно».

1. Прыгают по коробкам (по чему?), которые должны быть (**какими?**) кубическими.
2. Прыгают по коробкам (по чему?), которые должны быть (**какие?**) кубические.

Как правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбираем Т.п.:

**Прыгают по коробкам, которые должны быть (какими?) кубическими.**

Сравнить: Коробки были **кубические**, они должны быть **кубическими**.

Розенталь  http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/62.htm

Существительное и прилагательное в функции именной части составного сказуемого **могут стоять как в форме именительного, так и в форме творительного падежа**; ср.: И в семье его Савельич был свой человек (Мельников:Печерский). – И у Ивашиных он был своим человеком (Чехов); День был тусклый, теплый (Шукшин):

Обычно в этих случаях именительный падеж существительного указывает на у**стойчивый признак предмета**, на постоянно присущую ему качественную характеристику, а творительный падеж – **на временный признак**.Творительный падеж свойствен **книжной речи**, а именительный – **разговорной**.

Также учитываются и некоторые другие факторы.

Comment: Допускаете ли Вы, что можно иметь именительный падеж где-либо после инфинитива быть, например: *Савельич приложил немало усилий, чтобы быть свой человек в его семье*(?!)

Comment: Словосочетания и предложения строятся по-разному. Быть своим человеком - это словосочетание, глагол управляет Т.п. , но не может управлять И.п. В предложении связь между подлежащим и сказуемым называется координацией, при этом именная часть сказуемого может согласовываться с подлежащим в И.п. (Савельич был свой человек).  Но именная часть  сказуемого может быть выражена инфинитивом  с зависимым существительным , тогда падеж этого существительного сохраняется (Его задача - стать своим человеком). Ваш пример - это безличное инфинитивное предложение, управление Т.п.

Answer (score 0):

**Быть (какими?) кубическими.**

Глагол *быть* требует творительного падежа. Прилагательные мужского и среднего рода в творительном падеже отвечают на вопрос (каким?) и имеют окончание -ым, -им: хорошим, веселым.

Comment: _Глагол быть требует творительного падежа._ Вы не могли бы сформулировать точнее или дать ссылки? Нужны ведь какие-то оговорки, потому как можно же сказать: **быть беде**; **Ломоносов был великий человек** (А.Пушкин); **И глаза у нее должны быть синие** (Джек Лондон) и т.п.