# Я была маленькая или маленькой? В чем разница?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, падежи

Я сама научилась русскому языку. Но есть нюансы, которые меня интересуют.
В чем разница между этими предложениями? Какие из них правильнее по грамматике?

Когда я была маленькой... — Когда я была маленькая...
Он был тихим парнем. — Он был тихий парень.
Она была приятной девушкой. — Она была приятная девушка.

Answer (score 1):

На этом сайте не раз возникала эта тема. Можно найти немало ответов, если хорошо поискать. Вот свежий ответ (by Jasmin):

> Существительное и прилагательное в функции именной части составного сказуемого могут стоять как в форме именительного, так и в форме творительного падежа; ср.: И в семье его Савельич был свой человек (Мельников:Печерский). – И у Ивашиных он был своим человеком (Чехов); День был тусклый, теплый (Шукшин):
>
> Обычно в этих случаях именительный падеж существительного указывает на устойчивый признак предмета, на постоянно присущую ему качественную характеристику, а творительный падеж – на временный признак.Творительный падеж свойствен книжной речи, а именительный – разговорной.

([Не могу понять, какое из окончаний правильное](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/438078/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5/438081#438081))

Answer (score 1):

**В основе различения творительного (Т.п.) и именительного (И.п.) падежей лежит отношение ко времени.**

**В настоящем времени** при отсутствии связки мы говорим: **я сейчас маленькая** (И.п.).

**А вот прошлое может восприниматься по-разному:** мы или смотрим на него из настоящего и сравниваем два этих времени, или переносимся в прошлое, ощущаем себя в прошлом. В первом случае используется Т.п., во втором ― И.п.

Сравним частотность вариантов в Нацкорпусе: **я была маленькая** ― 642 примера,  **я была маленькой** ― 149 примеров, **я стала большая** ―  18 примеров,  **я стала большой** ― 20 примеров.

**Как мы видим, выбор падежа может зависеть от связки:** в этих примерах ***быть***  со значением   постоянного признака используется чаще, а ***стать***  ближе по значению к изменившемуся признаку.

Таким образом, можно говорить об общих факторах для выбора И.п. и Т.п., также есть мнение, что Т.п. более **современен**. Но в то же время очень многое ещё определяется  **конкретной ситуацией, стилем или является авторским решением.**

Вот, к примеру, комплимент для девушки: **ты в тот вечер была такой красивой/такая красивая.** Оба варианта возможны, но И.п. более эмоциональный, он позволяет видеть прошлое как настоящее.

Comment: за проверку в нацкорпусе плюс - класс

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО:

"я была маленькой" - это ответ на вопрос "я была кем?"

"я была маленькая" - это ответ на вопрос "я была какая?"

Первое явно про классификацию, и соответственно, про всю кучу особенностей данного класса, а второе - про какие-то отдельные признаки, по которым не обязательно классифицируют. Если признак такой, по которому классифицируют - то лучше использовать первую форму, а вторая будет ощущаться корявой. Так, например для меня сейчас корявой ощущается фраза "Она была приятная девушка".

И да, отношение к классу ощущается как более стабильное состояние, чем проявление каких-то признаков, которое чаще бывает временным. Бывают такие признаки, которые сами по себе временные. Соответственно, если нужно подчеркнуть временность, можно предпочесть вторую форму. Например, "я был голодный" (в тот момент) против "я был голодным" (в те времена).

Answer (score 0):

Эти словосочетания не являются взаимоисключающими и могут достаточно удачно дополнять друг друга.
Пример:

> Когда я была маленькая, я была маленькой. Но после 12 лет вдруг начала так быстро расти, что всерьез задумалась о модельной карьере.

По отдельности можно применять оба варианта. Неправильного среди них нет.

Comment: похоже вы перепутали два разных различия: различие языковой формы и различие значений конкретного слова. различие значений слова маленькая: маленького роста или маленького возраста? различие языковой формы: я была какой или я была какая? вопрос автора про различие формы, не нужно сюда примешивать ещё и различие значений слова маленькая.

Comment: @whyer, похоже Вы смешали отдельно взятую ситуацию в приведенном примере и саму концепцию, о которой говорится в моем ответе, поэтому у Вас сложилось ощущение путаницы. В своем ответе я пояснил, что оба варианта совершенно допустимы, и в качестве иллюстрации привел пример, в котором два словосочетания в РАЗНЫХ значениях успешно соседствуют в одном предложении.

Comment: у меня не случайно сложилось ощущение путаницы а потому что вы его создали, в вопрос об одной дихотомии приплетя другую совершенно не связанную но похожую дихотомию. зачем вы это сделали? намеренно чтоб запутать читателя или по ошибке? я решил что второе

Comment: Уважаемый @whyer, мне действительно очень жаль, что пример, в котором сочетаются две дихотомии сразу, Вас запутал, и Вам даже показалось, что здесь содержится какая-то ошибка. Я же совершенно осознанно объединил в одном фрагменте именно две дихотомии, чтобы наглядно продемонстрировать, как можно использовать две разные формы слова "маленькая" на практике. Ведь можно было сказать: "Когда я была маленькой, я была маленькой". И это тоже была бы формально верная фраза. Но посмотрите, насколько полезно здесь применение двух разных форм слова "маленькая". Именно это демонстрирует мой пример.

Comment: вводить вторую запутывающую дихотомию чтобы проиллюстрировать первую - нет никакой нужды. когда я была маленькая то писалась в штанишки, а когда ты была маленькой то ты тоже писалась, мам? - элементарно не вводя читателя  и без того запутанного первой дихотомией в ещё большую путаницу от добавления второй похожей.

Comment: и учтите что ваш пример создающий кашу из двух похожих дихотомий может запутать не только меня. (я-то впрочем и не запутался а лишь обратил ваше внимание на напрасно введённую вами усложняющую всё путаницу.)

Comment: а по _вашему_ примеру создаётся ложное впечатление что форма "была маленькая" означает только "была юная" а "была маленькой" - только "была низкой" - и не наоборот (т.к обратного употребления пример не приводит)

Comment: @whyer, это просто пример, а не двойное слепое плацебо-контролируемое тестирование. Здесь не нужны "обратные примеры" и прочие атрибуты серьезных научных исследований. Отнеситесь к этому проще ;)

Comment: не соглашусь. просто пример это наглядный пример. а в данном случае - не просто пример а запутывающий пример. т.е такой без которого лучше чем с ним

Comment: @whyer, это уже вопрос личных предпочтений. Мне нравятся яркие, запоминающиеся примеры. Вы, по-видимому, предпочитаете примеры более формальные, в какой-то мере даже "стерильные". Обе эти концепции имеют право на жизнь.

Comment: главное чтоб примеры делали предмет наглядней, облегчали понимание а не запутывали и увеличивали сложность

Answer (score 0):

Всплыл этот вопрос, попробую ответить исходя из своего опыта общения со студентами и преподавателями РКИ (русский как иностранный).

~1. Для практики формы эти не надо противопоставлять, принципиальной разницы между ними нету.

~2. Отношение ко времени, характеризующееся тем, что в прошедшем и будущем времени (но не в настоящем) возможны формы творительного падежа проявляется тут не напрямую, а опосредовано через неявное противопоставление состояние-свойство.

~3. Состояние лучше передается творительным падежом: ***я была маленькой*** - здесь подчеркивается, что характеристика выражаемое прилагательным "маленькая" - это состояние, которое может измениться, и скорее всего оно уже изменилось.
***Я была маленькой, поэтому меня не брали в поход.*** С тех пор ситуация изменилась, я выросла и хожу в походы.

Качество, которое неизменно на протяжении какого-то рассматриваемого автором отрезка времени, напротив, лучше выражается именительным: ***"я была маленькая и не поняла, что мне сказали***" - тут важен именно момент события, что было потом или до того, не рассматривается.

Остальные ваши примеры хуже поддаются такому разбору, но в общем-то тоже самое.

***Он был тихим парнем, а стал лидером, сильной и целеустремленной личностью***
***Он был тихий парень, непонятно за что его не любили*** - речь только о времени, за которое он не перестал быть тихим и парнем.

***Она была приятной девушкой, но вышла замуж и у неё изменился характер*** —
***Она была приятная девушка, у неё было много поклонников***

Более академическую формулировку - см. в цитате у М_Г, по сути я просто изложил положения этой цитаты применительно к вашим примерам.

Впрочем, всё сказанное не является абсолютным, это лишь предположение о том как воспринимаются эти формы большинством носителей. Но, полагаю, в рамках изучения РКИ вполне может пригодиться.

> *Творительный падеж свойствен книжной речи, а именительный – разговорной.*

Вот это спорно. Но оно и не очень принципиально.

Answer (score -1):

Думаю что это на ваш вкус, так как употребимы обе формы. Выбирайте любую и ошибки не будет. Мне предпочтителен родительный падеж.
"Он был тихий парень" звучит странно, а "Он был тихим парнем" нет.
Словом, дело вкуса.

Comment: Почитайте, пожалуйста, темы про пунктуацию на нашем форуме. У Вас с этим просто беда — в каждом сообщении по несколько ошибок. Я буду минусовать Ваши ответы, если ошибки будут совсем грубыми. Если Вы сумеете потом исправить ошибки, я заберу свои минусы.

Comment: Спасибо. Надо перечитать.